# Copy a folder to the build directory with meson

Tags: meson-build

I have a resource folder that needs to be copied to the build directory in a project using Meson build. I was using a custom_target like this:

```
  demo_res = custom_target('demo-res',
    input: ['demo/res/materials.yml'],
    output: ['res'],
    command: ['cp', '-r', meson.source_root() + '/demo/res', './'],
    install: false,
    build_by_default: true
  )
```

But, when testing a Windows build, it turns out the 'cp' command can't be called through a script in PowerShell and isn't available at all in cmd. I attempted to use 'copy', but for some reason this can not be called from meson as a command.

I'm aware of fs.copyfile, but that's only for single files and doesn't copy directories.

Is there some sort of cross-platform method, preferably internal to Meson, to copy a full directory full of multiple files to the build directory?

Comment: Why don't you use `install_subdir`?

Comment: Because this is for testing in the build directory, not for installation. As far as I know every method with the install_ prefix is only run when actually running an install procedure? Also, as for actual installation, what I'm trying to copy are actually resource files specifically for testing that I don't want to actually have installed during an install procedure.

Answer (score 4):

As of v1.2.0 your best option is likely...

```
subdir('demo/res')

# demo/res/meson.build
fs = import('fs')
fs.copyfile('materials.yml')
fs.copyfile(...)
```

The build directory will mirror the source directory, so you will have (at configure time) a structure like `<build>/demo/res/materials.yml`.

Comment: Please note I explicitly stated:
 > I'm aware of fs.copyfile, but that's only for single files and doesn't copy directories.
But I'm going to upvote your answer because if anyone comes here looking for an answer yours is, as of this point in time, the most correct way to do it with pure Meson.